# Regular expression to extract Section Number and Description

Tags: python, regex

Am having following data and I would like to extract section number and description in two separate strings.

I am using the following expression - `(\d+(?>\.\d+)*)(.\D*)`. However, in the description I am seeing `'. '`value and I want the dot to be in the section identified.

Can someone help me with this?

Here are my sample strings -

```
1.1.1. ABC
1.1.2. DEF
1.1.2.3. XYZ
```

Expecting -

```
No|Description
1.1.1.|ABC
1.1.2.|DEF
1.1.2.3.|XYZ
```

Comment: `re.findall(r'^((?:\d.)+)\s(\D+)', s, re.MULTILINE)` ?

Comment: Can't you just split by the 1st space only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.
Online demo of this is: [Online demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/Emzsmi/1/)

```
(?P<serial>(?:\d+\.)+)\s*(?P<description>\S+)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(?P<serial>           ##Starting a named capturing group named serial here.
(?:\d+\.)+)           ##Starting a non capturing group which is looking for continuous occurrence of digits followed with dot with 1 or more occurrences of this combinations.
\s*                   ##Looking for 1 or more occurrences of spaces here.
(?P<description>\S+)  ##Starting a named capturing group named description here which has all values except spaces occurrences.
```